# MS Access - CTRL-F search or replace for asterisk

Tags: ms-access, replace, escaping, wildcard, ms-access-2003

I am trying to search (or search and replace) using CTRL-F / CTRL-H (not queries as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895773/684229)) and I have a problem - how to find / replace asterisk (`*`)? It finds any field and replaces the whole field.

I tried:

```
"*"
\*
**
~*   source: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=126013)
[*]  source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/find-wildcard-characters-in-an-access-database-HA001171536.aspx
```

but nothing of this works! I am using MS Access 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaah, found the problem! I had selected "Compare: whole field", so it couldn't find it! When changing it to "Compare: any part", the `[*]` solution works!