# Wildcards in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, wildcard

I've written this SQL query in MS Access:

```
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE name  like '_a*'
```

Which produces no results, even though I have names like danny and sara in the Students table. 
THe '_' wildcard doesn't seem to work.

BTW,

```
like '*a*'
```

does return all names with a in them.

And ideas?

Comment: I would look at this related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign

Comment: You're mixing wildcard families -- if you're using * then for single characters, you use ?; if you're using % then for single characters it's _.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access query builder's dialect of sql, you need ? not _. If you connect to the same mdb backend via odbc you'll need to go back to using the standard wildcards.

See [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx?redir=0) for details.

Comment: For the full explanation, though, @Jeff O's citation is essential: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign

Comment: Thanks David! (few more characters)