# VB6 Syntax Question

Tags: sql, vb6

Can anyone tell me what this Asterisk(*) is for. `...tblpersonal where empid like '" & idNumber & "*'"`. What if I replace it with Percent sign(%), what would be the outcome?

Comment: ""what would be the outcome?"" what happens when you try?

Comment: This looks like SQL rather than VB code - what SQL engine is it? Mysql? MSSQL? Oracle?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's our written assignment... And I don't have soft here in our home.

Comment: What course are you taking that's using ***VB6***? Microsoft stopped supporting the VB6 development environment (Visual Studio 6) *entirely* a couple of years ago. The VB6 *runtime* remains supported for now, but the writing is on the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIKE condition allows you to use wildcards in the where clause of an SQL statement. This allows you to perform pattern matching. The LIKE condition can be used in any valid SQL statement - select, insert, update, or delete.

The patterns that you can choose from are:

```
% allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)

_ allows you to match on a single character
```

Next, let's explain how the _ wildcard works. Remember that the _ is looking for only one character.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name like 'Sm_th';
```

This SQL statement would return all suppliers whose name is 5 characters long, where the first two characters is 'Sm' and the last two characters is 'th'. For example, it could return suppliers whose name is 'Smith', 'Smyth', 'Smath', 'Smeth', etc.

Here is another example,

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers
WHERE account_number like '12317_';
```

The same way u can use asterisk (*) instead of (%)

I hope its help to you

Answer (score 1):

The Percent (%) sign in SQL says "match any number of characters here".  E.g. `LIKE '%test'` will match abctest, `LIKE 'test%'` will match testabc

The Asterisk character looks like it'll match a literal *, e.g. matching all empids ending with an asterisk (depending on the version of SQL - see below)

EDIT: See [Microsoft Jet wildcards: asterisk or percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign) for a more in depth answer on * vs %

Comment: I voted this up based on the link provided to another thread.  It would be much better though if it actually stated that LIKE wildcards vary in Jet SQL depending on whether the Jet OLEDB Provider vs. DAO (or ADO with the Access ODBC Driver) is being used.

Comment: The reality even varies further.  When using the Jet 4.0 Access ODBC driver you can optionally use the new SQL-92 syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712547(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Bob Riemersma: thanks, I edited the linked answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more a SQL syntax question than a VB6 one. :-)

You haven't mentioned what database this is talking to (I assume it's talking to a DB). The asterisk is not generally special in SQL (or VB6 strings), and so that query will look for `empid` being `like` whatever's in your `idNumber` followed by an asterisk. Probably not what was intended. If you replace it with a `%`, you'll be looking for any `empid` that *starts with* whatever's in your `idNumber` variable. If the column is numeric, it will be converted to text before the comparison.

So for instance, if `idNumber` contains `100`, say, and there are `empid` values in the database with the values `10`, `100`, `1000`, and `10000`, the query would match all but the first of those, since "100", "1000", and "10000" are all `like` "100%".