# MS Access 2007 Query Returns No Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using the following query to find client who are from the medicine department:

```
SELECT client.clientID, client.firstname, client.lastname, client.organization,
       client.department, client.email, events.Date, events.title,
       eventAttendance.eventID, eventAttendance.clientID,
       eventAttendance.attended
FROM client INNER JOIN 
     (events INNER JOIN eventAttendance ON events.id = eventAttendance.ID) 
     ON client.clientID = eventAttendance.clientID
WHERE client.organization like '%medicine'
```

In the table, the possibilities are "School of Medicine" and "Department of Medicine;" however, no records are returned.  What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wild card character in Access is a * not an %

change your sql like so:

```
like '*medicine'
```

Comment: This did return some more results.  When I try
WHERE client.organization = 'School of Medicine', nothing is returned.  Why would that be?

Comment: @aparker81 - Not sure, but I would guess that there are some extra characters padded on the front or the end of the text. You can test this theory by trying this: client.organization like '*School of Medicine*'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It did not return the results.  Perhaps I'll make another question out of it.

Comment: @aparker81- Sorry I left out the *, I meant: client.organization like '*School of Medicine\*'

Comment: The wildcard character in Access can be either `*` or `%` depending on ANSI Query Mode or can be `%` regardless of ANSI Query Mode by using the `ALIKE` keyword. For more details, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign/720896#720896).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is likely that you do not always have an event, so you need LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT client.clientID, client.firstname, client.lastname, client.organization,
       client.department, client.email, events.Date, events.title,
       eventAttendance.eventID, eventAttendance.clientID,
       eventAttendance.attended
FROM client LEFT JOIN 
     (events LEFT JOIN eventAttendance ON events.id = eventAttendance.ID) 
     ON client.clientID = eventAttendance.clientID
WHERE client.organization like '*medicine'
```