# What is wrong with this OleDBCommand?

Tags: .net, ms-access, oledb

In .NET 4.5 I am trying to execute an OleDBCommand on an access database.

The code I have is

```
Dim rows As Integer
Dim dbCommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dbTransaction As OleDb.OleDbTransaction

Call gOleCn.Open()
dbTransaction = gOleCn.BeginTransaction
dbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("", gOleCn, dbTransaction)
dbCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Tレイヤ管理 SET レイヤー=0 WHERE 名前 LIKE '水田_*';"
rows = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The query executes fine in access itself, but in .NET it never affects any rows.
It works if I change the CommandText to `"UPDATE Tレイヤ管理 SET レイヤー=0 WHERE 名前='水田_" & Parameter & "'"` and specify the name exactly using `Parameter`, but then I'd have to write a loop, whilst with `LIKE` it's all done in one line.

But how can this be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the accepted answer to this SO question: [Microsoft Jet wildcards: asterisk or percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign)

Since you're using OleDb, you are using ANSI-92 query mode, so must use `%` instead of `*` as the wild card character.  The reason your `UPDATE` worked within an Access session is that it uses ANSI-89 query mode by default.

```
"UPDATE Tレイヤ管理 SET レイヤー=0 WHERE 名前 LIKE '水田_%';"
```

If you intended the `_` (underscore) character to match the literal character (instead of the ANSI-92 wild card for any single character), make it a single-member character class in the pattern:

```
"UPDATE Tレイヤ管理 SET レイヤー=0 WHERE 名前 LIKE '水田[_]%';"
```

I'm not sure what happens with those unicode table and field names.  From your question it sounds like they may not be causing problems.  However, if nothing else works, I would try enclosing them in square brackets:

```
"UPDATE [Tレイヤ管理] SET [レイヤー]=0 WHERE [名前] LIKE '水田[_]%';"
```

Comment: That was it (`%` instead of `*`)! Thanks a billion :)