# Like query for excel database in java script

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access

I have written some Javascript code and am trying to fetch data from an MS Access database.

I am able to fetch from the table with `select *` statement but unable to execute the like query.
I am using the below query:

```
 strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE (((Sheet1.Name) Like '*i*'))";
```

The result shows no record found, and if I replace this with the below:

```
 strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE (((Sheet1.Name) = 'i'))";
```

This works.

Could anybody help me on this?

Comment: could it be the space in your like condition: like *i * which should be like *i* ? - bah somehow it's messing up my comment on those characters..eseentially you have a space in the like clause, which you need to remove I believe

Comment: Thanks for writing JanR, i have kept the space here only to post it properly in the, otherwise it was looking somthing else.. in my code its '*i*'.

Comment: ahh cool I was having the same issue.

Comment: In standard SQL, the wildcard character in `LIKE` is `%`, not `*`. Assuming this is true of Access/Excel (your title says one but the text says the other), I think you want `WHERE (((Sheet1.Name) Like '%i%'))`

Comment: Thanks... That worked.. :)
Actually in access/Excel its *i* but what you have suggested is working fine.

Comment: I nominate @IMSoP to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: Incidentally, to escape characters from causing formatting, like `*i*` rather than *i*, you need to surround them in "backticks": `

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many pattern matching functions, the standard wildcard for "zero or more of any character" in SQL's `LIKE` operator is `%`, not `*`.

Thus where other functions would use the pattern `*i*`, a standard SQL `WHERE` clause would be

```
WHERE (((Sheet1.Name) Like '%i%'))
```

According to [this documentation page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HP005188185.aspx), Access actually uses two different sets of wildcards in different situations, which it refers to as "ANSI-89" and "ANSI-92" (refering presumably to different SQL standards, although this seems an odd thing to have changed):

> Access supports two sets of wildcard characters because it supports two standards for Structured Query Language — ANSI-89 and ANSI-92. As a rule, you use the ANSI-89 wildcards when you run find or find-and-replace operations against Access databases. You use the ANSI-92 wildcards when you run queries against Access projects — Access files connected to Microsoft SQL Server databases. Because SQL Server uses the ANSI-92 standard, Access projects also use the ANSI-92 standard. However, Access also provides an exception to that rule.

Not knowing Access, that really doesn't clear things up for me, but it seems that in the ANSI-89 syntax, the wildcard is indeed `*`, so *in some situations* your query would be correct, but the particular setup you have is using the "ANSI-92" mode, so it needs to be the version with `%`.

There is further discussion on this question: [Microsoft Jet wildcards: asterisk or percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/719115/157957) The difference appears to be whether you are connecting with DAO or ADO, which is all greek to me and makes my head hurt.

Comment: Access uses * as it's wildcard character. I wonder why % works in this case.

Comment: Hm, OK, I've never used Access - actually, I'm not at all clear what technology the OP is using, since they mention Excel, Access, and Javascript, but post only the SQL (albeit with names which look very like spreadsheet references to me).

Comment: It seems that Access uses different conventions depending on the project type / settings. Answer updated with reference.