# SQL LIKE doesn't find obvious matches

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OS
WHERE OS.VERSION LIKE '%1%';
```

In my table there are rows with char 1 in it. However, it returns an empty result.
I changed a little bit the LIKE clause to different values, but it still doesn't work.

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: lets see your data and schema

Comment: "SQL" Like does work :P

Comment: Well, like the LIKE operator *does* work .. so review your expectations. (And give us reason to believe in your expectations - i.e. provide data/schema or a SQL fiddle.)

Comment: What is the data type of `OS.VERSION`?

Comment: It's in MS Access. How can I do it?

Comment: Which database are you using, what does your schema look like, what data is in the table?

Comment: OS_NAME- text
VERSION- text
PRICE- integer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try double-quotes and * for wildcards.  You are using Oracle syntax instead of Access syntax.

Comment: It'd be more correct to simply say MS-Access doesn't support standard SQL `LIKE` syntax.  Even SQL Server supports it properly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: @ebyrob While the default setting in Access is to use `*` (which is consistent with how you do the same operation in VBA) You can also use `%` if you set your queries to be made in compliance with ANSI-92 SQL. JET, the db under Access, pre-dates SQL-Server so it's not surprising they get to do their own thing a bit here...

Answer (score 0):

LIKE operation can't be used with columns of integer type. I assume that OS.Version is of integer type?

Edit1:
If you are referring to MS Access then you have to do the LIKE with stars (*) instead of %.