# SQL Query need to find a specific word

Tags: sql, ms-access

I looked and found a similar question, still not working. I am working in ACCESS for class, and this is the only query I can't get right.

I need to be able to list Products that have the word 'Green' in ANY part of the ProductName

I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductName LIKE '%green%';
```

It runs without error, but returns nothing. It is all spelled correctly, and there IS a product that contains "green"

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard in MS Access is '`*`', not '`%`' (unless you explicitly set an ANSI-compatible query mode):

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductName LIKE '*green*';
```

Comment: Oh my gosh... THANK YOU! It worked, now I feel silly. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's more accurate to say that the wildcard is '*' in some situations, but '%' in others. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign for a full discussion.