# ADODB wild card operators other than %

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like, adodb

I've seen many questions explaining that the `*` wildcard character from Access is `%` when using ADODB.  But what about `?`, `#` or the other wildcards and patterns you can use with [`LIKE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) in Access?  It seems they don't work either over ADODB, do they just have no equivalent?

Comment: See [Access wildcard character reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-AF00C501-7972-40EE-8889-E18ABAAD12D1) for explanation of wildcard differences between ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 query modes.

Comment: Just a general translation from Access LIKE patterns to ADODB LIKE patterns which seems to be ANSI-89 to 92.  That link is basically the answer, @HansUp.

Comment: OK.  Also see whether you like `ALike`: [Microsoft Jet wildcards: asterisk or percentage sign?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/720896/77335)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match any single alphabetic character:

```
?
```

is equivalent to

```
[A-Za-z]
```

---

Match any single numeric character:

```
#
```

is equivalent to

```
[0-9]
```