# SQL request on MS-Access with Like statement seems to be never working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried several "Like" syntax on one request, (I'm using VB.NET and a MS-ACCESS 2010 database), and none of them could get any other result than throwing an exception.Why? I'm not having any idea about that.

I did this workaround : Instead of

```
SELECT dbFieldDisplayName FROM dbTableName WHERE dbFieldSearchName Like 'A*'
```

(I also tried with 'A%' instead of 'A*')

I Used:

```
SELECT dbFieldDisplayName 
FROM dbTableName 
WHERE dbFieldSearchName >='A' AND dbFieldSearchName <'AZZZ'
```

Does anybody know why my Like statement always triggers exception? Any better workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: Did you try LIKE 'A%' intead of 'A*'? (percentage instead of star)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Jet wildcards: asterisk or percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign)

Comment: I tried A% and A* with the same result: "parameters are missing in your request" (or similar to this)

Comment: That usually means that a field name is misspelled.

Answer (score 3):

If  you need  the rows with col values startin with A you should use  like  with %

```
SELECT dbFieldDisplayName FROM dbTableName WHERE dbFieldSearchName Like 'A%'
```

(in SQL * ...mean all columns ..not all char)

Comment: In your query there is not paramter so  show the real query and  a proper data sample  ...  e  ..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, what a strange behaviour of my MS-ACCESS...

I uninstalled all my office components (including MS-ACCESS), and  installed it all again, and now the 'Like' statement works fine, with a % as a wildcard.

The request:

**SELECT dbFieldDisplayName FROM dbTableName WHERE dbFieldSearchName Like 'A%'**

works now fine, as it was supposed to be working.