# oledbexception is thrown for input that's accepted by access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm building a small phonebook application and I'm storing phones in an access database in table called phones whose fields are : FullName,Job,Phone1,Phone2,Notes and SN primary key.

I've set fullname and phone1 to required and set validation rule for fullname to `Len([FullName])>3` and validation rule for both phone1 and phone2 to `Like "[0-9]*"`, I also set validation messages for the validation rules.

In a wpf application I've added the access database using visual studio to generate the dataset and tableadapter code, this is MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="253" Width="685">
<Grid Height="206" Width="658">
    <Label Content="FullName" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,16,0,0" Name="FullName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" />
    <Label Content="Job" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,46,0,0" Name="Label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,46,0,0" Name="Job" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" />
    <Label Content="Phone1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,75,0,0" Name="Label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Phone2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="269,16,0,0" Name="Label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,75,0,0" Name="Phone1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="325,21,0,0" Name="Phone2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
    <Label Content="Notes" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,56,0,0" Name="Label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="95" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="325,60,0,0" Name="Notes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" />
    <Button Content="Save" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,161,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" />
</Grid>
```

this is save click handler :

```
private button2_Click(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PhonesDataSetPhonesTableAdapter.Insert(FullName.Text, Job.Text, Phone1.Text, Phone2.Text, Notes.Text);
    } catch(OleDbException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }        
}
```

the `PhonesDataSetPhonesTableAdapter` is defined like this :

```
Global.projectName.PhonesDataSetTableAdapters.PhonesTableAdapter PhonesDataSetPhonesTableAdapter = new Global.projectName.PhonesDataSetTableAdapters.PhonesTableAdapter();
```

When I launch application and put `John` as fullname and `programmer` as job and `2137976` as phone1 number an OleDbException is thrown with the validation message for phone1 which is

> your phone number contains letters, it should only contain numbers

but it doesn't contain any letter and when I try the same input through access it accepts it, what's going on here ? and how do I make it work.

Comment: Note that your expression only evaluates the first character of the phone number. Any other  characters can be letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OleDb driver requires a different wildcard character in its `Like` statement. Instead of `*` it now wants a `%` (which is ANSI-92).

If I change in MS Access the validation rule to `Like "[0-9]%"` I can insert rows with a phonenumber "123" by calling insert on that tableadapter.

The downside of this is that in Access you can no longer insert values as Access now expects the literal character % after a single digit.

If you want both your application and access to work, using the Odbc driver would work.

Here is some background on the issue: [Microsoft Jet wildcards: asterisk or percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign)