# asterisk or percentage sign in impala

Tags: sql, impala

> The percentage sign (%) is used as the "everything" wildcard instead of an asterisk. It will match zero or more characters.

As [@onedaywhen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/720896/8625228) said, the two have same function.

But in impala, I find they only work in different specific situation.

## show tables like ' '

Suppose in my database `opd`, there are there table,

- `opd.haha`
- `opd.haha1`
- `opd.abc`

input:

```
show tables like 'haha*'
```

output:

```
opd.haha
opd.haha1
```

input:

```
show tables like 'haha%'
```

output:

```
Done. 0 results.
```

## select ... like

```
select 'haha' like 'ha%' -- true
select 'haha' like 'ha*' -- false
select 'haha' like 'ha__' -- true
select 'haha' like 'haha%' -- true
```

My question is that

To summarise,

- asterisk sign only works in show tables clause, and
- percentage sign only works in select clause

Is this comment right?

Comment: The like used with the show uses a [unix style](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_show.html), hence the `*`. While a like used in standard SQL uses `%`. It's like but it's not alike.

Comment: I find `*` only works in show statement. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's probably that way because `SHOW` doesn't seem to be standard SQL. But they needed to include a pipe `|` (OR). And in SQL the syntax for LIKE doesn't have an OR character.  Besides, according the documentation the LIKE word is optional after a SHOW.

Comment: Yes, in the `where` or `select` statement, OR operation is like `var like 'A' or  var like 'B' ` instead of  `var like 'A|B' `

Answer (score 1):

The standard wildcards for `like` are:

- `_` which represents a single character
- `%` which represents zero or more characters

`like` does not implement regular expressions.

If you want regular expressions, then use `regexp_like()`.