# "#" LIKE pattern character does not work in SQL in Access 365? A new bug in Jet SQL engine?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like, jet

From [wildcard characters supported by Microsoft Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-wildcards-in-queries-and-parameters-in-access-ec057a45-78b1-4d16-8c20-242cde582e0b) I cannot get the `#` working in SQL statement. A minimalized example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysObjects WHERE "123" LIKE "#*"

return value for "#*": 0
return value for "*": 56
```

It works only in the VBA Immediate Window (I know that the evaluation there is actually different, but anyway):

```
? "123" LIKE "#*"
True
```

All other pattern characters seem to work fine. But since the above linked page declares the `#` to be usable in SQL statements, is this a bug? Or am I misreading the documentation?

Version info says: `Version 1905 (Build 11629.20246 Click-to-Run)`

Setting `SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)` is off. (In Options > Object Designers.)

---

UPDATE: A commenter [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960835/like-pattern-character-does-not-work-in-sql-in-access-365-a-bug-in-jet-sql#comment100459998_56960835) it works as expected in Access 2010. It also [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960835/like-pattern-character-does-not-work-in-sql-in-access-365-a-new-bug-in-jet#comment100460110_56960835) in Access 2007 and 2016 Pro Plus [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960835/like-pattern-character-does-not-work-in-sql-in-access-365-a-new-bug-in-jet#comment100460302_56960835) in Access Office 365 Business 1906 11727.20230.

I tried changing collation to General (Options > General > New Database Sort Order) and then creating a new database but the issue is still present there.

Comment: There are several syntactical differences between the Jet engine and the Access user interface (including VB).  If using the Jet engine directly, use SQL wildcard characters.

Comment: @rd_nielsen – yes but could you show me what I am not doing correctly compared to the official documentation?

Comment: More information is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign

Comment: @rd_nielsen – sorry, that is a different topic, not addressing my question

Comment: The code works as expected in Access 2010.

Comment: @forpas – yes, this is what I was afraid of... it worked and it stopped since some version. Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: Can confirm non-zero results in Access 2007 & 2016 Pro Plus (1906)

Comment: Can confirm non-zero results in Access Office 365 Business 1906 11727.20230

Comment: @LeeMac – Thanks for trying all that. Then it may look like an issue caused by an application environment? I changed Options > General > New Database Sort Order := General  and created a new database, but the issue still persists there. Will wait for arrival of Office 1906 which you used for testing.

Comment: For the sort order, check `CurrentDb.CollatingOrder`, it tends to behave finicky (needs a compact & repair before it takes effect, changing it only changes it for a specific database for the next compact and repair).

Comment: Also note: Access supports per-field collation. If you're comparing 2 constants, I wouldn't have a clue what collation is used. For tests, it's more sensible to compare to an actual field and check that fields collation first (`CurrentDb.TableDefs("SomeTable").Fields("SomeField").CollationOrder`). The database collation order will change the default for new fields, but I'm not sure if the database collation order is used when comparing two constants.

Comment: @ErikA – Thanks, I'll check it. Since other characters always work, this now looks like a bug anyway.  Will wait for Access ver. 2019-06 to confirm the behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

In Access, the numbers symbol (#) is the delimiter for dates stored as a string.

You need to "escape" the special character, by wrapping it in square brackets, like this:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
FROM MSysObjects 
WHERE (((MSysObjects.[Name]) Like "[#]*"));
```

Note: your query is searching for a string starting with a hash inside a literal string "123" - that probably won't work either.